# qemu-img does less compression than expected

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, image-compression

I have created a Virtual m/c in virt-manager and copied a directory containing 2GB of data and deleted it.

Then I have shutted down my VM and used the below command to compress it

qemu-img convert -c -p -O qcow2 original.qcow2 compressed.qcow2

Then the final image(compressed.qcow2) size is 3GB.

But here my question is, if I didn't copy the 2GB directory content to VM and do the procedure of shutting it down and compressing then the final image(compressed.qcow2) size is 1GB

Why does this happen?

Any pointers helpful

Comment: it might be in the trash, how did you delete it within the VM?

Comment: rm -rf my_directory. And I am using ubuntu12.04 server edition

Answer (score 0):

I have done in the following way to reduce the final image size.

Attached a disk and mounted a volume, then copied the huge data of 2GB into the added drive. Then the root image size is reduced to same as 1GB.

The problem which I have identified is, if we write some data in a VM and delete it. Then the deletion will not be proper and it occupies partition table with random blocks, which reduces the compression rate as expected.

I think the way which I tried to reduce size is not proper, is there any way such that it works even with root partition.